# Information about logon time and logout time for Linux users

Tags: linux, shell

Does anyone know how to collect information about logon and logoff time for Linux user, and calculate the time spent on system in that month.

Answer (score 0):

Linux stores user logins and logouts in `/var/log/wtmp`. The command `last` prints a list of all historical user logins and logouts for the system and the time at which they logged in and out. Using these you can build up a way to identify the amount of time a user has used the system for.

Check the man pages for more information. The `/var/log/wtmp` file is a binary file with a system specific struct for reading and writing it so you may have to write a C program to get the specific output you want.